# PHP SOAP Client for Java Web Service

Tags: java, php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have built a wsdl using Java's web services and an running it on localhost(wamp). I am trying to create a PHP SoapClient for the wsdl but it says 'Extra content at the end of the document'. But when I try to run the service using a Java Client or a .NEt Client it runs the wsdl.

I've tried searching it on the net but still couldn't find the problem. Please help.

Here's how I am creating the SoapClient:

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://localhost/path/to/ServiceSever?wsdl', array('trace' => 1));
```

I've also tried to run it by creating a SoapServer and then create a client from it:

```
$server = new SoapServer('http://localhost/path/to/ServiceSever?wsdl');
$server->addFunction('getinfos');
$server->handle();
```

Comment: Kind of tough to help you without seeing any code or what you've done to debug it

Comment: Hi John Conde. This is all about the code I have. The wsdl is per-generated using Java's web service.

Answer (score 0):

I use this to create the soapClient call in PHP given a runnning wsdl
http://sourceforge.net/projects/wsdl2php/

and here you can find the documentation
http://www.urdalen.no/wsdl2php/manual.php

give it a try